# Virtual host not working in Apache2 Ubuntu 14.04 after doing all steps

Tags: apache2, localhost, virtualhost

I am trying to make name based virtual hosts in Apache2 with Ubuntu 14.04, after doing all these step, I am redirected to localhost but not to the file on my virtual directory.
What I already did;

- set up vdc.local.conf file with

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName vdc.local
  ServerAlias www.vdc.local
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /media/luzan/Backup/Dropbox/vdc/vdc.local/public_html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- changed hosts in /etc/hosts

  ```
  127.1.1.1 vdc.local
  ```
- added this to apache2.conf in /etc/apache2/

  ```
  <Directory /media/luzan/Backup/Dropbox/vdc/vdc.local/public_html>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ```
- from terminal did

  ```
  sudo a2ensite vdc.local.conf
  ```
- restarted apache2 using

  ```
  sudo service apache2 reload
  ```

After doing all this I am redirect to localhost page when i navigate to vdc.local in web browser.

Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page

I have login.html inside that vdc.local/public_html/ folder and again when I navigate to vdc.local/login.html, I getting 403 Forbidden Error.

Did all this did I missed anything there? I have a folder in that document root too.

Comment: Well, the 403 is probably due to a permission error. What are the permissions of those folders?

Comment: I have set permission to Read and Write for all folders of that root.

Comment: Try `namei -mo /media/luzan/Backup/Dropbox/vdc/vdc.local/public_html` apache2 need grant to access each directory. take a look to this [link](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied).

Answer (score 0):

The apache package comes with a default config in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/, I think it's called 000_default.conf or something like that, which by default responds to any request on port 80, regardless of the hostname. Use `sudo a2dissite` to disable it and restart apache.